# Rake Cucumber on RVM 1.8.7-p334

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rake, rvm

Im hitting a bit of a wall when running `rake cucumber` on my dev environment using rvm ruby-1.8.7-p334 I get the following output

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `desc' for #<Cucumber::Rake::Task:0xb7208958>
/home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@regenersis/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:140:in `define_task'
/home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@regenersis/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:136:in `initialize'
```

The doozy is the same codebase, same gem versions work perfectly on a non-rvm setup

Comment: Ooops typo in the title... its ruby-1.8.7-p334